# Swift UISeachController add nav bar on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I currently have my `UISearchController` set up so it is presented over the nav bar once the search icon is clicked.

```
var searchController: UISearchController!

@IBAction func searchMe(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Create the search results view controller and use it for the `UISearchController`.
    let searchResultsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SearchResultsViewController.StoryboardConstants.identifier) as! SearchResultsViewController



    // Create the search controller and make it perform the results updating.
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = Colors.blue
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    // Present the view controller.
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I am using a different `searchResultsController` than the current table view to display results. The problem is that when a cell is selected in the `searchResultsController` a `segue` is performed to a new view controller (the users profile) and there is no navigation bar.

I need a back button to appear to take the user back to the `searchResultsController`. I have tried a bunch of different segues, setting the nav bars on the storyboard but nothing seems to work. My initial thought was to make this line of code:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
```

point to a nav controller with `searchResultsController` as its root view controller but I had no luck. Any help is great! Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any solution?